# Automated asynchronous socket tests

Tags: c#, sockets, nunit

I would like to make a few automated tests to make sure my transport layer is working correctly. The problem is that I use asynchronous UDP sockets and the test finishes before my callback is called. I would like to test basic scenarios like sending a few bytes and test they were received correctly at the other side.

The question is: What is the most effective way to automate tests with asynchronous sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data delivery happens on a different thread you need to block your test waiting for the notification from the receiving callback, probably with a timeout.

Comment: What I did is not really elegant but  it works. A simple Sleep(2000) before my call to Verify() on my mock did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by asynchronous socket? Using the asynchronous programming model?
If you want to test the transport layer, then I would focus on this and not so much on asynchronous socket. 
For testing the transport layer, you can test with two sockets from two threads. One thread reading, one writing. I assume that your protocol does already support ping messages.

Comment: I use Socket.BeginReceiveFrom for receiving data. One of the issues I have is that the test function exits before the BeginReceiveFrom callback is called.